# Why is StyleSheet's ownerNode null after insertion?

Tags: javascript, css, cssom

Can somebody explain why a `StyleSheet`'s `ownerNode` is `null` after I set its `textContent` to something?

```js
const style = document.createElement('style')
document.head.appendChild(style)
const sheet = style.sheet
// passes
console.assert(sheet.ownerNode !== null, 'ownerNode is null')
sheet.ownerNode.textContent = 'div { color: red }'
// fails
console.assert(sheet.ownerNode !== null, 'ownerNode is null')
```

Comment: Fascinating question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by completely replacing the text of the node, you've created a **new**, replacement stylesheet object:

```js
const style = document.createElement('style')
document.head.appendChild(style)
const sheet = style.sheet
sheet.ownerNode.textContent = 'div { color: red }'
console.log(style.sheet === sheet);           // <===== false!
console.log(style.sheet.ownerNode === style); // <===== true
```

The old one isn't in the DOM anymore, so it doesn't have an `ownerNode`.